# Run Pipeline REST API queue time variables not appearing

Tags: rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1 to run a pipeline.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/company/project/_apis/pipelines/38507/runs?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

```
HEADERS
Content-Type & Accept =  application/json
```

I was able to trigger it, however I cannot seem to put together the body to create the queue time variables.

```
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/master"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "sequenceNumber": 65
    },
    "variables": {
    }
}
```

I also tried using "runParameters", "templateParameters" was giving me an error.

Here's a screenshot of the pipeline without the queue time variables:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this:

```json
{
    "resources": {
        "repositories": {
            "self": {
                "refName": "refs/heads/master"
            }
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "sequenceNumber": {
            "isSecret": false,
            "value": 65
        }
    }
}
```